# How to Implement Tf-idf without using libraries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, machine-learning, nlp

Sklearn does few tweaks in the implementation of its version of TFIDF vectorizer, so to replicate the exact results you would need to add following things to your custom implementation of tfidf vectorizer:

1. Sklearn has its vocabulary generated from idf sroted in alphabetical order
2. Sklearn formula of idf is different from the standard textbook formula. Here the constant "1" is added to the numerator and denominator of the idf as if an extra document was seen containing every term in the collection exactly once, which prevents zero divisions. IDF(t)=1+(loge((1 + Total number of documents in collection)/(1+Number of documents with term t in it)).
3. Sklearn applies L2-normalization to its output matrix.
4. The final output of sklearn tfidf vectorizer is a sparse matrix.

I tried to implement it **without using libraries** but getting an error which I'm unable to debug.

Code:

```
corpus = [
         'this is the first document',
         'this document is the second document',
         'and this is the third one',
         'is this the first document',
         ]
  

def fit(dataset):    
    unique_words = set() # at first we will initialize an empty set
    # check if its list type or not
    if isinstance(dataset, (list)):
        for document in dataset: # for each review in the dataset
            for word in document.split(" "): # for each word in the review.#split method converts a string into list of words
                if len(word) < 2:
                    continue
                unique_words.add(word)
        unique_words = sorted(list(unique_words))
        vocab = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(unique_words)}
        
        return vocab
    else:
        print("you need to pass list of sentance")

vocab=fit(corpus)
print(vocab)
output:{'and': 0, 'document': 1, 'first': 2, 'is': 3, 'one': 4, 'second': 5, 'the': 6, 'third': 7, 'this': 8}

def idf(unique_words):
    idf_dict={}
    N=len(corpus)
    for i in unique_words:
        count=0
        for row in corpus:
            if i in row.split():
                count+=1

        idf_dict[i]=float(1+math.log((N+1)/(count+1)))

    return idf_dict

def transform(dataset,vocab):
    rows = []
    columns = []
    values = []
    if isinstance(dataset, (list,)):
        for idx, row in enumerate(dataset): # for each document in the dataset
            # it will return a dict type object where key is the word and values is its frequency {word:frequency}
            word_freq = dict(Counter(row.split()))
            # for every unique word in the document
            for word, freq in word_freq.items():  # for each unique word in the review.                
                if len(word) < 2:
                    continue
                # we will check if its there in the vocabulary that we build in fit() function
                # dict.get() function will return the values, if the key doesn't exits it will return -1
                col_index = vocab.get(word, -1) # retrieving the dimension number of a word
                # if the word exists
                if col_index !=-1:
                    # we are storing the index of the document
                    rows.append(idx)
                    # we are storing the dimensions of the word
                    columns.append(col_index)
                    td = freq/float(len(rows)) # the number of times a word occured in a document
                    idf_ = 1+math.log((1+len(dataset))/float(1+idf(word)))
                    values.append((td) * (idf_))
                    
        return normalize(csr_matrix( ((values),(row,columns)), shape=(len(dataset),len(vocab))),norm='l2' )
    else:
        print("you need to pass list of strings")

print(transform(corpus,vocab))
```

Error:

```
 TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-20-8da73617fb69> in <module>()
    ----> 1 print(transform(corpus,vocab))
    
    
         22                     td = freq/float(len(rows)) # the number of times a word occured in a document
         23                     a=idf(word)
    ---> 24                     idf_ = 1+math.log((1+len(dataset))/float(1+idf(word)))
         25                     values.append((td) * (idf_))
         26 
    
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict_values'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; it is a good idea to post your code & error in separate snippets (edited).

Comment: Most probably in the end you'll want to compare your results against those of sklearn's  TfidfVectorizer, so instead of `document.split(" ")` you may think about using their default regex tokenizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
idf(word) -> dict
```

That function idf returns a dictionary.  idf seems to take in the corpus so call it earlier in the function and then just access the word your trying to get.

```
tmp_dict = idf(corpus)

...
idf_ = 1+math.log((1+len(dataset))/float(1+tmp_dict[word]))
```